# Why Am I Getting a Non-terminating decimal expansion when I am rounding up already?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

OK, so I'm trying to divide 2 random BigDecimal values. If the number is uneven or irregular rather than get the remainder, I would prefer to round it up to the nearest whole number. However, when I do this my website crashes and I get the following error.

Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.

I would understand this happening if I hadn't been already rounding the digits, but because I am, I don't understand why this is happening.

```
  BigDecimal cartQty= (testValue1).getQuantity().getValue();
  BigDecimal cartMultiplier = (testValue2).getQuantity().getValue();
  //below where it crashes so if 4/3 and the value is 1.333 I'd expect to get 2.
  BigDecimal TotalPackageInt=  cartQty.divide(cartMultiplier ).setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell `BigDecimal` how you want to round when you do the `divide`.  Like this:

```
BigDecimal TotalPackageInt=  cartQty.divide(cartMultiplier, 0, RoundingMode.UP );
```

Comment: You sir, were a great help. I knew it was order of operations issue, but did not know how to use rounding mode in that context. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you understand the intent of the operations doesn't change the semantics of the actual Java method chain.

Your statement starts with `cartQty`, then calls `divide(cartMultiplier)` on it. Only *after* that returns is `setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP)` called on its result. If the division throws an exception, then what you planned to do later doesn't matter.

Given that these are quantities, you might consider using `BigInteger` instead of `BigDecimal`.